# Subquery issue, Returns SQL error when "AS" and "AND" are used

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is what im trying to run in full:

```
$data = $this->db->select('main.UID, main.value')
                 ->select('twitch_streams.UID AS twt')
                 ->select('(SELECT value FROM user_profile WHERE UID = main.UID AND key = "twitch" AND subkey = "update" LIMIT 1) AS check', null, FALSE)
                 ->from('user_profile AS main')
                 ->join('twitch_streams', 'twitch_streams.UID = main.UID', 'left')
                 ->where('key', 'account')
                 ->where('subkey', "TWT")
                 ->get();
```

With this it returns:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = "twitch" AND subkey = "update" LIMIT 1) AS check FROM (`user_profile` AS m' at line 1
```

But if I shorten the SELECT to `->select('(SELECT value FROM user_profile WHERE UID = main.UID LIMIT 1)', null, FALSE)` it doesn't return an error but it returns the wrong value as the key: `[(SELECT value FROM user_profile WHERE UID = main.UID LIMIT 1)] => 1405874916 )`

Comment: can you also paste plain sql so we can make CI active record for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key is a reserved word in mysql,wrap it with back ticks.Check is also a reserved word....

[Look here and avoid them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

Comment: That returns as "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check FROM (`user_profile` AS main) LEFT JOIN `twitch_streams` ON `twitch_stream' at line 1"